# Vlookup based on selectizeInput

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny, vlookup, selectinput

I'm currently creating a web app using R shiny. I have an existing data frame (imported from excel) and want to create a smaller table to display in the web app.

The original data frame (imported) looks like this (but larger):

```
ID      date        colour
1231    1972/02/28  red
1314    1966/01/18  blue
1476    1980/11/18  green
2356    1995/03/09  orange
1332    1991/09/10  white
```

I've created a sidebarpanel where the user can select the ID that they want to display information for:

```
sidebarPanel(selectizeInput("ID","Select ID",choices = DF$ID, selected = "1332"))
```

and i want to create a smaller table which will show the date and colour based on the ID selected in the sidebarpanel e.g. IF ID = 2356 is selected, I want the Table to display the following:

```
ID      2356
date    1995/03/09
colour  orange
```

Is there a way I can vlookup the date and colour based on the ID? I've tried using the following:

```
webapp_table = data.frame(matrix(ncol = 1,nrow = 2))
x2 = c("Date","Colour")
row.names(df2) = x2

webapp_table[1,1] = reactive({req(input$policynumber)
                     dt = as.Date(DF$date[which(DF$ID== input$ID)])
                     return(dt)})
```

but I get the following error:
Error in x[[jj]][iseq] <- vjj :
incompatible types (from closure to logical) in subassignment type fix

Comment: https://mastering-shiny.org/action-dynamic.html?q=filter#dynamic-filter

Answer (score 1):

I would take it step by step, as discussed in the code's comments

```r
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

# Get the data
data <- tribble(
  ~ID,      ~date,         ~colour,
  1231L,    "1972-02-28",  "red",
  1314L,    "1966-01-18",  "blue",
  1476L,    "1980-11-18",  "green",
  2356L,    "1995-03-09",  "orange",
  1332L,    "1991-09-10",  "white"
  ) 

# Find the unique choices to lookup 
values_ID <- data |> 
  distinct(ID) |> 
  arrange(ID) |> 
  pull(ID)

# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Lookup App"),

  # Add a dropdown for ID 
  sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
          selectInput(
            inputId = "id", 
            label = "Select an ID", 
            choices = values_ID
            )
          ),

      # Show the output
      mainPanel(
         tableOutput("table")
         )
      )
  )

# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  # Filter the data based upon the lookup
  data_lookup <- reactive({
    data |> 
      filter(ID == input$id)
  })

  # Display the output
  output$table <- renderTable({
    data_lookup()
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I hope that helps.